# Securing WLAN using one time authentication

Tags: wireless, security, cisco-wireless

We have a wireless SSID for Managers which I need to secure using one time authentication. Currently we are using MAC filtering but it is insecure. So I am wondering if there is a certificate based authentication or any one time authentication as it will be inconvenience to enter a password in every connection.

Comment: What kind of controller are you using?  And by one time authentication, do you mean one time password (i.e. token)?

Comment: We use Cisco 5508 WLAN. I meant any type of authentication which won't asked the user for authentication every time he want to connect.